# ¿Puedo convertir un nvarchar en un time?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo que hacer unos cálculos con unos datos de un tabla, la cual tiene registradas unas horas como varchar y obviamente no puedo procesar las fórmulas con este tipo de dato.
¿Alguien alguna idea de como pasar estos datos a time?, y si se puede, ¿Puedo con ellos por ejemplo hacer proceso de suma y resta con esos datos?

Formato de la tabla:

```
  CREATE TABLE RECUENTO_TRANSFERENCIAS(
    id_rec int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    usuario_rec nvarchar(50),
    fecha_rec date null,
    hora1 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora2 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora3 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora4 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora5 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora6 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora7 nvarchar(10) NULL,
    hora8 datetime NULL);
```

Los campos que debo de convertirlos son los que dicen horas....
Así son los registros.

```
3667    Alejandra Arango        2020-04-23  06:04:50    10:34:09    10:46:22    14:19:37
3668    Jaime Roldan            2020-04-23  NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
3669    Juan Ferraro            2020-04-23  08:03:48    13:53:04    NULL        NULL
3670    Fidel Mauricio Ramirez  2020-04-23  05:58:22    14:09:39    NULL        NULL
3671    Andres Restrepo         2020-04-23  08:04:48    NULL        NULL        NULL
3672    Erika Velasquez         2020-04-23  05:25:13    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

como ven, el nvarchar contiene hora, minuto y segundos(hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server tiene un tipo de dato que se llama así mismo [time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), y según la tabla de conversiones (de las funciones [CAST and CONVERT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) la conversion de NVARCHAR a TIME es implícita, pero puedes hacer las conversiones de manera explicita para manejarlos.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT N'06:04:50' AS [Sin Convertion], CAST(N'06:04:50' AS TIME(3)) AS [CAST], CONVERT(TIME,N'06:04:50') AS [CONVERT]
```

Resultado:

```
Sin Convertion  CAST    CONVERT
06:04:50    06:04:50.000    06:04:50.0000000
```

En caso de desear realizar operaciones, puedes utilizar la función DATEADD:

```
DECLARE @horaInicio TIME(3) = '06:04:50';
DECLARE @agregarMinutos INT = 5;
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @agregarMinutos, @horaInicio);
```

Resultado:

```
06:09:50.000
```

En vista que tienes horas y minutos, en una columna separada de la hora, puedes jugar convirtiendo la hora a NVARCHAR y concatenarla a la hora o hacer un proceso similar, así tendrías un dato DATEIME.

```
SELECT Fecha, Hora1, Hora2, CAST(Fecha AS DATETIME)+CAST(Hora1 AS DATETIME) AS [FechaHora1], CAST(Fecha AS DATETIME)+CAST(Hora2 AS DATETIME) AS [FechaHora2]
FROM (
VALUES(CAST('2020-04-23' AS DATE), N'06:04:50', '10:34:09'),
      (CAST('2020-04-23' AS DATE), NULL, NULL),
      (CAST('2020-04-23' AS DATE), '08:03:49', '13:53:04')
) AS A(Fecha, Hora1, Hora2)
```

Resulado:

```
Fecha   Hora1   Hora2   FechaHora1  FechaHora2
2020-04-23  06:04:50    10:34:09    2020-04-23 06:04:50.000 2020-04-23 10:34:09.000
2020-04-23  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2020-04-23  08:03:49    13:53:04    2020-04-23 08:03:49.000 2020-04-23 13:53:04.000
```

Update: Si esta entre tus posibilidades, cambia el tipo de data de nvarchar(10) a time(0), te ganaras algún espacio y rendimiento en las consultas.

Saludos

Comment: Es bueno recordar que también tenemos las opciones TRY_CAST() y TRY_CONVERT() para convertir datos inválidos en nulos en vez de generar errores.